# ExtJS learning tutorials. Cant create window

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm following the tutorial for ExtJS 4.x but I can't figure out something. I have this class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.LoginWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',

    title: 'Log in',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
                {
                    extend: 'Ext.Window',
                    title: 'Log in'
                },
            ]
        });

        MyApp.LoginWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

which is in my app.js file. But I don't know how actually I can create a new window using this script in the file where I'm actually using this script. I guess it's something simple, but don't want to go ahead before figure this out.

Thanks
Leron

Comment: I don't think you followed a tutorial to write that. Stick to sencha's docs and examples if you want to learn ExtJS 4

Comment: You may go and see the tutorial by yourself it's literally copy-paste from there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically doing one very little thing - extend your class from `Ext.Window` and change title of it. But you don't need your `initComponent` function as it is right now - it just doesn't make sense and doesn't do anything.

After you defined your class you can create an object by doing something like this:

```
var win = Ext.create('MyApp.LoginWindow', {

});
win.show();
```

Comment: It seems that in this case .show() is the key to solve the problem.It seems that with the right MVC application architecture you may not need .show() function, but if you follow the tutorial strictly that's the only solution to do it. Thanks for your answer.